# hyperkube gets stuck while trying to start the API server

Tags: docker, kubernetes, google-compute-engine

I am running Kubernetes 1.5.0 in hyperkube and it gets stuck with the following lines cyclically repeating in the logs:

```
E0228 21:28:35.891472   20321 reflector.go:188] pkg/kubelet/config/apiserver.go:44: Failed to list *api.Pod: Get http://localhost:8443/api/v1/pods?fieldSelector=spec.nodeName%3D127.0.0.1&resourceVersion=0: dial tcp 127.0.0.1:8443: getsockopt: connection refused
E0228 21:28:35.892410   20321 reflector.go:188] pkg/kubelet/kubelet.go:386: Failed to list *api.Node: Get http://localhost:8443/api/v1/nodes?fieldSelector=metadata.name%3D127.0.0.1&resourceVersion=0: dial tcp 127.0.0.1:8443: getsockopt: connection refused
```

Here is how I am starting Hyperkube:

```
docker run \
    --volume=/:/rootfs:ro \
    --volume=/sys:/sys:ro \
    --volume=/var/lib/docker/:/var/lib/docker:rw \
    --volume=/var/lib/kubelet/:/var/lib/kubelet:rw \
    --volume=/var/run:/var/run:rw \
    --net=host \
    --pid=host \
    --privileged=true \
    --name=kube -d \
    gcr.io/google-containers/hyperkube:v1.5.3 \
    /hyperkube kubelet --containerized \
    --hostname-override="127.0.0.1" \
    --address="0.0.0.0" \
    --api-servers=http://localhost:8443 \
    --allow-privileged=true --v=2
```

Comment: Are you sure the API server is on the same machine, listening on port 8443?

Answer (score 0):

To second the comment from @nehal-j-wani, `8443` is the secure port, but you're using the `http` scheme, without any client or CA certificate.

Sounds like you are not intending to communicate with your local API server over TLS, so you should rather either:

- use the insecure port (defaults to `8080`)
- fix your kubelet flags to use the TLS communication properly

See also:

- [kubelet](https://kubernetes.io/docs/admin/kubelet/)
- [TLS bootstrapping](https://kubernetes.io/docs/admin/kubelet-tls-bootstrapping/)